# Upgrade to Tomcat 8.5 gives 500 internal server for working application URL

Tags: iis-8.5, tomcat8.5

I upgraded Tomcat server from 8.0 to 8.5. The web server is IIS. Binding in IIS server was www.test.abcurl.com for port 80. The application URL is http://test.abcurl.com.
After the upgrade, http://test.abcurl.com returns 500 internal server error.

But,

1) http://test.abcurl.com:8080 works
2) I changed the binding from www.test.abcurl.com to test.abcurl.com in IIS and http://test.abcurl.com started working.

Both 1) and 2) puzzle me. How is this related to Tomcat upgrade to 8.5? Please help to enlighten.

P.S: I had also tried changing connector port to 80 in server.xml initially, which did not work.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't understand your issue clearly. Do you mean you modifyed the url from www.test.abcurl.com to test.abcurl.com in IIS then it works well? Could you please post the details error message about the 500 error? You could find the details error message in the event viewer.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Answer to your question is yes. I could not find any logs in Event viewer->Windows logs->Application, nor in IIS logs. Tomcat server 8.0 seemed to work for binding www.test.abcurl.com

Comment: Have you cheked the Tomcat server's logs to find out some related error message? If there is no error message, we couldn't find out the reason and solution. Besides, if you could reproduce this issue, I suggest you could try to enable the FRT to find out more details information. About how to enable the FRT, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).